# Editing .gitattributes to normalize line endings doesn't work?

Tags: git, line-endings, gitattributes

I am trying to normalize line endings for my git repo, specifically, I am trying to make all .sh files use LF (Unix-style endings).
When I researched about it, I figured out I should add this to my .gitattributes file:

```
*.sh eol=lf
```

That doesn't work... It doesn't change .sh file endings to LF..
Could anyone tell me what I should do?
Thank You!

I also tried `* text=auto eol=lf` and `git config --global core.autocrlf false`

Comment: If your files and checkout already exist, doing all those things doesn't do anything to the existing files - you need to recommit/recheckout. Does doing `git add --renormalize .` and then committing the files do what you want?

Comment: @wkl thank you!! deleting the .sh file, commiting, bringing it back and commiting again worked!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## TL;DR

Use `git add --renormalize` (e.g., `git add --renormalize .`).

## Long

The directives *in* a `.gitattributes` file just tell Git *what to do*.  They don't actually *do* it.  As a result, simply changing an existing `.gitattributes` file, or adding a new one, has no effect *yet*.

Each attribute you can specify has some particular meaning.  Unfortunately, the CRLF-line-endings attributes meanings are blurry:

- there are contradictory settings;
- there is a lot of history: Git did certain things in the past, but it turned out to be terrible; but existing behavior can't be changed for compatibility reasons, so it still does that, but now it does *these other things too;* and
- it's very hard to *observe* these things actually *happen*.

The result of the middle item is that what to set depends on which Git version(s) you're using.  There are some general rules that always apply though, and you should keep these in mind as you experiment.  Also, keep in mind that as initially written, Git never messed with line endings at all, and that's usually the default setting in most initial installations.

#### Three copies of files

First: Git has two kinds of transformation.  To explain this properly, we must start a bit further back, with the difference between *committed* files, files in Git's *index* or *staging area*, and files in your *working tree*.

When you're working with files in Git, there's always<sup>1</sup> a *current commit*.  That's the commit you selected when you ran `git checkout` or `git switch`, for instance, to pick the branch `main` or `develop` or whatever.  That branch name has a distinguished *latest* commit,<sup>2</sup> and that's the commit you are now using.  Every commit contains a full snapshot of every file,<sup>3</sup> as a sort of permanent archive.  Most version control systems do the same thing, though each VCS has its own way of doing this: one key point of version control is, after all, to be able to get back the old versions.

So, *one* copy of every file, for the current commit, is stored, permanently and unchangeably, *in* that particular commit.<sup>4</sup>  This copy *can* have either kind of line ending, especially if you have not told Git to mess with line endings.  These copies will have whatever line endings they have, and *they cannot be changed*.  They are immutable!

In order to *use* a version control system that stores an immutable copy of every file—such as Git—that version control system *has to* provide you with a *mutable* copy too.  So Git does this too: when you *check out* some commit, making that commit the current commit, Git *copies all the files out of that commit* into your working tree.

Now, this is a deliberate overstatement: Git will *sometimes* short-cut things by doing *nothing*, whenever Git (thinks it) can get away with it, because doing nothing is so much faster and more efficient than doing something.  (Exercise: which is a faster way to get home, when you're already home: driving to the airport, flying to Paris and back, and driving home, or just staying home?)  The details on *when* Git thinks it can get away with it get fairly complicated, and aren't completely relevant to understanding the line-ending issues.  But we'll come back to this in a bit.  For now, this is where the *third* copy of each file comes from: Git wrote it into your working tree when you checked out the commit.

The weird thing about Git—compared to many / most other version control systems at least—is that Git keeps an *in-between* copy of each file too.  This in-between copy is in the internal *format*, ready to go into a new commit.  But unlike the committed copy of a file, which is entirely immutable, Git lets you *replace* the internal copy, using `git add`.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, *almost* always.  In a new, totally empty repository, for instance, there are no commits yet.  That means there's no *current* commit.  You can re-create this oddball situation using `git checkout --orphan` or `git switch --orphan` as well.  Whenever necessary, Git handles this internally by using its [semi-secret empty tree](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9765453/1256452) *as if* it were the current commit, or more precisely, the current commit's tree.

<sup>2</sup>The act of adding a new commit simply adds a new *latest* commit, updating the branch name appropriately.  The commit that *was* latest becomes the second-latest (except that when using `git commit --amend`, the commit that was latest is kicked off the end of the branch instead).

<sup>3</sup>These snapshots are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and—importantly—*de-duplicated* format, so that the repository doesn't bloat up even though—or perhaps I should say *because*—most commits mostly re-use earlier file contents.

<sup>4</sup>Technically, the storage is indirect, via a `tree` object—hence the fake empty tree.

---

#### Two kinds of transformation

Start with the the "three copies" model, where for each file, there's one in the current commit, one in Git's index / staging-area, and one in your working tree:

```
HEAD (commit)   staging area   working tree
-------------   ------------   ------------
README.md       README.md      README.md
Makefile        Makefile       Makefile
main.py         main.py        main.py
```

Remember that `git checkout` or `git switch` has to *copy* the committed files.  Those copies go into both the index / staging-area *and* the working tree.

When Git is copying a file "out" like this, that's a great time for Git to do some transformations.

The `git add` command takes a working tree file—presumably, one you've *updated*—and compresses it and checks for duplicate contents.  Then it updates Git's index/staging-area with the new copy.  This compression requires *reading* the working tree copy, and *writing to* the index copy.  That's *also* a great time for Git to do some transformations.

When you run `git commit`, to make a new commit, Git simply *packages up the prepared index contents*, without doing any transformations at all on the content of each file.  So Git doesn't do *any* transformation here at all.

**All the end-of-line transformations, then, happen in the copying from index to working tree or from working tree to index.**  In other words, they happen while checking out (or `git restore`-ing) a file, and while `git add`-ing a file.  That's the natural place to put them, so that's where Git puts them.

Next, Git *chooses*—I emphasize that this is a choice, because it is—that *if it's going to mess with line endings, it will always store the frozen archival committed copies with LF-only, Unix-style line endings.*  If you want Git to store, in the committed copies, CRLF / Windows-style endings, you can't have Git do this for you.  That's just the way this is, and unlike some of Git's other earlier mess-with-line-endings decisions, nobody seems to have serious objections to this, so I don't see it changing in the future.<sup>5</sup>

The two kinds of transformation that Git is willing to do, then, are:

- while copying *to* working tree (checkout et al), Git can turn LF-only to CRLF;
- while copying *from* working tree (`git add`, mostly), Git can turn CRLF to LF-only.

*All of the settings you can set are all about when to have Git do this.*  The `text` setting tells Git that it should treat a file as text (as opposed to binary, which should never be mangled this way), and the `eol=` tells Git what kind of line endings should appear in your *working tree* (with implied LF-only in the archival copies).

You can enable *just* the `git add` side CRLF-to-LF operation with the `input` setting, or you can enable both sides—checkout and `git add`—with the other settings.  And that's it!  **Well, almost.**

---

<sup>5</sup>On the other hand, [it is difficult to make predictions, especially about the future](https://quoteinvestigator.com/2013/10/20/no-predict/).

---

#### Git tries to be lazy

Remember how I mentioned that Git will do nothing, if it thinks it can get away with it.  Unfortunately, when you change the `.gitattributes` setting or other settings for line endings, Git often still thinks—incorrectly this time!—that it can get away with doing nothing.

When you run `git add path/to/file`, or even `git add path\to\file` on Windows, Git looks at cache information it stores in its index / staging-area entry for the file `path/to/file` (that's the file's name, complete with the forward slashes).  This information hints to Git as to whether you've modified the file since Git extracted it earlier.  If Git decides, based on this, that you *haven't* modified the file, *Git does not bother to re-add the file*.

This has historically been a big problem, so `git add` gained the `--renormalize` option in Git version 2.16.  This option acts as a sort of big hammer, defeating the optimization entirely.

#### Seeing what's really in the repository

Whenever you *look at a file* by viewing it in an editor or file-browser, you're seeing the *working tree copy*.  This isn't the copy that's in any commit!  In particular, it's been de-compressed and un-de-duplicated, so that you can see it in the first place.  In the process, it may have its line endings messed-with.

To view what's really in the repository, it's helpful to know that `git cat-file -p` will extract a *blob object's* data without doing any text conversions (unless, that is, you add `--textconv` and appropriate extra information).  So if you have a [hex editor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hex_editor), you can use `git cat-file -p` to read out the raw committed-file contents, and view those in your hex editor, to see what's actually *in* the repository.  You can do the same with blob-ized contents in Git's index / staging-area.  Remember that `git rev-parse` can tell you hash IDs:

```
git rev-parse HEAD:Makefile
git rev-parse :Makefile
```

(and of course `git ls-files --stage` dumps out the entire index contents, including the hash IDs).  Most Git commands, including `git cat-file`, can take revision IDs that include pathspecs, so `git cat-file -p HEAD:Makefile` also works.  (This also provides the path information for `--textconv`.)

(You'll always want something like a hex editor, so that your file-viewer doesn't make invisible characters invisible.)